# Need Critique on my solution. Convergence in probability of a product of sequences of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Came across this problem in my self education. Found 4 solution here, but none looked simple enough to me... So I cooked up one of my own. Now it looks too simple :) Am I missing something?
I would really appreciate any constructive critique on my solution[image: Sorry for being a dumb-head and not using Latex]

Comment: What do you mean by "$Y_n$ is bounded"? Do you mean that the sequence $(Y_n(\omega))_{n}$ is bounded for each $\omega$?

Comment: What I meant to say was: Since every convergent sequence is bounded both above and below. So it's upper and lower bounds exist. By boundedness I mean that all elements of a bounded seqience are within certain interval, excluding possibly finite number of elements. Does this clear things out?

Comment: I know what a bounded sequence is. The problem is simply the following: In order to apply your argumentation you need that $X_n(\omega)$ is convergent for each $\omega$, i.e. that $(X_n)_n$ is convergent almost surely. But it is only assumed that $X_n$ converges in probability. (Note that a sequence $(X_n)_n$ converging in probability is not necessarily bounded.)

Comment: Good point! Thank you! So if I just leave absolute values of X and Yn instead replacing them with M my argument should still work...

Comment: No, not exactly, because you need a uniform bound, i.e. something of the form $$\max\{|X_n|,|Y_n|\} \leq M$$ for *all* $n$ and $M<\infty$ almost surely. The second condition is a problem: Since $(X_n)_n$ is (in general) not bounded, we cannot expect that $M<\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: I mean if I don't define this M at all and don't ise boundedness. Instead I just keep |X| and |Yn| in my inequality. Those are positive numbers so movind them to the right at the end does not change inequality.

Comment: I see. Okay, so that's the next problem. If $M$ is some random variable, then it not obvious that $$\mathbb{P}(|Y_n-Y|> \frac{\epsilon}{2M}) \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$. Mind that $Y_n \to Y$ in probability implies $$\mathbb{P}(|Y_n-Y|> \frac{\epsilon}{2c})$$ for each **constant** $c>0$ (by "constant" I mean that is does not depend on $\omega$; in particular we cannot simply choose $c=M$.)

Comment: Thanks much! I felt something was missing. I'll have to work that out.

Comment: Yeah... here is a hint: Use $$\mathbb{P}(|M| \cdot |Y_n-Y| \geq \epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(|M| \geq R) + \mathbb{P}(|Y_n-Y| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{R}).$$ [And (+1) for showing your effort.]

Comment: Thanks again! I could take R=n so it would go to infinity as n goes to infinity? and the limit with R and |M| would obviously be zero?

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful. As we have discussed above, $M$ depends on $n$ (since you want to replace $M$ by $X$ and $Y_n$, right?). So, e.g. the term $\mathbb{P}(|M| \geq R)$ becomes something of the form $$\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq R)$$ and if we choose $R=n$, then (in general) we cannot expect $$\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq n) \to 0.$$ So: yes, we want to let $R \to \infty$, but "independently" from $n$.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Greatly appreciated!As you can tell I have just started with probability and statistics so have a lot to learn.

Comment: Yeah, no problem, you are welcome. (And, actually, I'm female, but never mind. :)) If you don't get along with it, I can write you an answer (tomorrow, I guess), so that you can see what you have to change in your proof.

Comment: Oops... Sorry about that! Now I get why you were so patient with me :)  I really have to be a bit more careful with what I type :) I'll try to complete the proof and post a new version. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me summarize the issues we already discussed (in the comments):

- You cannot apply  the theorem of boundedness of convergent sequences since this would require that $X_n(\omega)$ converges for *each* $\omega \in \Omega$ (i.e. almost sure convergence) - but here only convergence in probability is assumed. In fact, it is not difficult to construct a sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges in probability but is unbounded.
- At the end of the proof you use $$\mathbb{P} \left( |Y_n-Y| > \frac{\epsilon}{2M} \right) \to 0 \quad \text{as} \, \, n \to \infty$$ for a random variable $M$. Mind that convergence in probability does only imply $$\mathbb{P} \left( |Y_n-Y| > \frac{2\epsilon}{c} \right) \to 0$$ for some *constant* $c>0$ (by "constant" I mean that it does *not* depend on $\omega$).

Here is a sketch how to fix your proof:

---

Using a very similar argumentation as in your question, we can show that

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n Y_n-XY| \geq \epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(|Y_n| \cdot |X_n-X| > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) + \mathbb{P} \left( |X| \cdot |Y_n-Y| > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) =: I_1+I_2.$$

We estimate the terms separately. For $I_1$ note that

$$\begin{align*} I_1 &\leq \mathbb{P}\left(|Y_n| <R, |Y_n| \cdot |X_n-X| > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) + \mathbb{P} \left( |Y_n| \geq R, |Y_n| \cdot |X_n-X| > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \\ &\leq \mathbb{P} \left( |X_n-X| > \frac{\epsilon}{2R} \right) + \mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq R) \tag{1}. \end{align*}$$

Now

$$\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq R) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(|Y_n-Y| \geq \frac{R}{2} \right) + \mathbb{P} \left( |Y| \geq \frac{R}{2} \right). \tag{2}$$

If we plug $(2)$ into $(1)$ and let $n \to \infty$, we get

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left(|Y_n| \cdot |X_n-X| > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right)\leq \mathbb{P} \left( |Y| \geq \frac{R}{2} \right).$$

Finally, we can let $R \to \infty$ and conclude

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left(|Y_n| \cdot |X_n-X| > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) = 0.$$

A similar (even easier) argumentation applies to $I_2$. Consequently,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n Y_n-XY|  \geq \epsilon)=0.$$

Comment: Many thanks saz!!! This approach is much better than mine. I also posted my attempt here. Vielen Dank Frau!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the great help from saz, I made an attempt to complete the proof(but found out later that the very same way was already presented here)

Never the less, Many thanks to saz!!![image]

Comment: Great, you did it on your own. (+1)

Answer (score -1):

I don't like these sorts of proofs that unnecessarily dive into a sea of $\epsilon$'s. Consider the following alternative characterization of convergence in probability.

**Theorem.** $X_n \to X$ in probability if and only if for every subsequence of the $X_n$ there is a further subsequence that converges to $X$ almost surely.

See, e.g. Williams: *Probability with Martingales* exercise EA13.1.

Using this theorem, let's prove your result. Suppose $X_n \to X, Y_n \to Y$ in probability. Let a subsequence $X_{n_k}Y_{n_k}$ of $X_nY_n$ be given. By the theorem take a subsequence and then another subsequence so that we have a subsequence on which $X_{n_{k_\ell}},Y_{n_{k_\ell}}$ both converge almost surely. Then of course $X_{n_{k_\ell}}Y_{n_{k_\ell}}$ converges almost surely to $XY$, so the theorem implies $X_nY_n \to XY$ in probability.

I encourage you to try and prove this theorem, it is not very difficult (though it will require some $\epsilon$'s which are, in my opinion, better spent on the theorem than your result.)

Comment: Thank you nullUser. Your proof is among those four existing answers I found. All of them are very useful and I have worked out details of all four.  My problem with those proofs was that they all use other("more sophisticated") theorems to prove quite simple result. I wanted to do it using just definition and basic properties.

Comment: The proof of this "more sophisticated" theorem that I'm using is much shorter than the $\epsilon$ heavy proof you provide. I don't mean to criticize, only to provide food for thought that one of the greatest features of mathematics is to be able to build powerful tools that one can use throughout one's mathematical career.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't mind critique since I asked for it. I'm just not sure if "not liking" my proof is a constructive critique :) As I have stated in the very beginning, I'm well aware of the existence of other, better proofs. What I wanted to know was if something was wrong with my proof. (Besides the fact that my epsilons are not well spent :) ) Again, thanks much for your answer and I would really appreciate if you could take a time to analyse mine and give me your oppinion on it's completeness.